# How to stop index process in running

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, indexer

We have currently some process indexing in running.

How I can stop this?

We tried already some things like:

MySQL restart didn't work as we could not do it
MySQL kill -9, didn't work, but we could kill it, but the indexing process still running

I tried to find some lock files, but I didn't find any.

Any clue, what else we can check?

We are using Magento 1.9.1

Comment: do you mean it is showing running state in index management?

Answer (score 7):

Stopping the indexing process is an easy task. When Magento starts indexing, it updates the status in the table index_process to working. If the script stops working due to some error or server problem, the status will remain the same as working and it won’t bring the process back to pending automatically.

One solution is to login into your database via PHPMyAdmin (or any other tools) and run the below program. Don’t forget to fix the error before running the query.

```
UPDATE `index_process` SET `status` = 'pending' WHERE `status` = 'working';
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the Magento has created the locks in the db during the indexing and it hasn't released them after that.
Try to get the list of the process by:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

Then try to kill them by process id like this:

```
KILL 341;
```

Use the actual process ids instead of the `341`.
I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 2):

Go to "var/locks" from root of your magento then delete all files in it. It contains all index process files. But first take a backup 'locks' directory.

Comment: I do not have var/locks

Comment: In your version of Magento there is no var/locks folder. You have to use Abhinav Singh's solution. I mean using the database query UPDATE `index_process` SET `status` = 'pending' WHERE `status` = 'working';